# Как реализовать модерацию новых записей, постов в Django 2.1?

Tags: python, django

Я начинающий разработчик на Django 2.1. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Никак не могу найти решение.
Я хочу модерировать новые созданные записи. То есть, чтобы в админке можно было поставить галочку на модерации, и только после этого пост публиковался бы.
Но в идеале, конечно, чтобы администратор мог видеть новые записи прямо на сайте и модерировать прямо там.
Реализация самого создания нового поста:

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    moderation = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=True)
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'body']
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import PostForm

class PostCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return response
```

**admin.py**

```
from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'user', 'moderation')

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^posts/$', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='posts'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
]
```

Хочу, чтобы былою, как на рисунке. Либо чтобы админ сразу на сайте мог смотреть и модерировать запись (было бы здорово).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAubL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

```
class PostListView(ListView):
   ...

   def get_queryset(self):
      queryset = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset()
      return queryset.filter(moderation=True)
```